# Problems generating addresses using bip32

Tags: electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, deterministic-wallets

I'm trying to generate bip32 addresses using the following (the PHP version).

https://github.com/prusnak/addrgen

The author provides a test MPK which I can get working that looks like this:

```
675b7041a347223984750fe3ab229df0c9f960e7ec98226b7182a2cb1990e39901feecf5a670f1d788ab29f626e20de424f049d216fc6f4c6ec42506763fa28e
```

However, the MPK I export from electrum does not work. Its much shorter and looks like this:

```
xpub661MyMwAqRbcGntu46CZtzegh5V3vT624SJqPVUgqzboX6A39f1hb8vEMrG555gV5QzVXEpPXqwayMQKu1ZKKRLkX9AoFvqPwAm3qL24AnE
```

The exact message I get is

```
pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit x
```

Any idea whats going on? Why does electrum's MPK not resemble the authors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addrgen author here!

Addrgen was created before Electrum was BIP-0032 compatible and thus it used different master public keys and derivation method.

Please check the following PHP implementation which supports BIP-0032:

- https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php

For python there are couple of implementations available, e.g.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bip32utils
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycoin/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitcoin/

Comment: Bitwasp guy here, maybe check out https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php  rewrote the old library - src/Key/HierarchicalKeyFactory.php is probably what you need